# Contracting an effective Cartier divisor to a point

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, formal-schemes

I am trying to understand contractibility of a subspace, in the case of contracting a divisor to a point. More precisely, what I mean by contraction is the following.

Given an algebraic space(or complex analytic space) $X$ and a subspace $Y$ of $X$, I want to know when we have a map $f:X\to X'$ to another algebraic space $X'$ such that $f$ is an isomorphism on $X\setminus Y$ and $f(Y)$ is a single point in $X'$.

Now the situation that I am caring about is when $Y$ is an effective divisor of a smooth variety $X$. One sufficient condition is that the normal bundle is anti-ample. Now suppose we have a decomposition $Y=Y_1+Y_2$ where $Y_i$ is also an effective Cartier, so that $Y$ is geometrically a union of two irreducible codimension 1 subvariety and $Y$ is connected. Assume moreover $\mathcal{O}_Y(Y)$ is not anti-ample but $\mathcal{O}_Y(aY_1+bY_2)$ is anti-ample for some integers a,b>1. In this case, can we conclude anything about contractibility of $Y$?

What I was trying to do is to apply Vo Van tan's result in his paper 'On Grauert's conjecture and the characterization of Moishezon spaces'. There, all I need is ample conormal sheaf $I/I^2$ where $I$ is the ideal sheaf supporting on $Y$. The problem is, I don't understand the terminology used there, especially 'ideal sheaf supporting on $Y'$. Does the line bundle $O(-aY_1-bY_2)$ with $a,b>1$ still count as ideal sheaf supporting $Y$?